# Dynamically setting CheckBox and get if all checkbox is checked

Tags: android, checkbox

```
ArrayList<String> toDoArray = XYZ.getChecklistItems(reasonToCal);
for (int i = 0; i < toDoArray.size(); i++) {
    final CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox(this);
    checkbox.setText(toDoArray.get(i));
    checkbox.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    checkLinearLayout.addView(checkbox);
}
```

I am dynamically setting checkbox in my layout.
The problem I am facing is i cannot get if all my checkbox is checked so that i can enable the button if all checkboxes are checked

Comment: Have an integer variable that increases or decreases at each Check on a CheckBox. If the integer variable = numOfCheckBoxes then enable the Button. You can enclose it in a method and call it from each click handler (or from the centralized handler). EASY.

Comment: implement listener that will maintain a count of checked checkboxes, update count on depending the status of view.

Comment: can you please provide me with lines of code. That would be helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can implement common listener for all check-boxes which will increase variable of checked check-boxes and also decrease is user will uncheck any you should also keep somewhere total numbers of check-boxes and compare those two variables - if equals set enabled on button.

That can be one approach.